# Grunt Does Not Watch JS files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have been spending over an hour on this one, looked through several questions, but the answer is nowhere to be found.

I am running into a problem when using watch on my javascript files. All of the other files are watched and the tasks are executed properly.

If I run the default from the start, concat and uglify are working perfectly fine, but if I make any changes to a js file, watch will just plainly ignore it.

This is my file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {
            index: {
                src: ['js/shared/*.js', 'js/index/*.js'],
                dest: 'js/concat/index.js',
            },
            page: {
                src: ['js/shared/*.js', 'js/page/*.js'],
                dest: 'js/concat/page.js',
            },
        },

        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files:{
                    'js/build/index.min.js': 'js/concat/index.js',
                    'js/build/page.min.js': 'js/concat/page.js',
                }
            }
        },

        sass: {
            options: {
                outputStyle: 'compressed',
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'css/main-unprefixed.css': 'sass/main.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        autoprefixer: {
            global: {
                src: 'css/main-unprefixed.css',
                dest: 'css/main.css'
            }
        },

        jade: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    pretty: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '',
                    src: [ '_layouts/jade/*.jade' ],
                    dest: '_layouts',
                    flatten: true,
                    ext: '.html'
                }]
            }
        },

        shell: {
            jekyllServe: {
                command: "jekyll serve --no-watch"
            },
            jekyllBuild: {
                command: "jekyll build"
            }
        },

        open : {
            build: {
                path: 'http://localhost:4000',
                app: 'Firefox'
            }
        },

        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            site: {
                files: ["*.html", "**/*.html", "*.md", "**/*.md", "**/*.yml", "*.yml", "!_site/*.*", "!_site/**/*.*"],
                tasks: ["shell:jekyllBuild"]
            },
            scripts: {
                files: ["js/*.js", "js/**/*.js"],
                tasks: ["concat", "uglify", "shell:jekyllBuild"]
            },
            jade: {
                files: ["_layouts/jade/*.jade"],
                tasks: ["jade"]
            },
            css: {
                files: ["sass/*.scss", "sass/**/*.scss", "sass/**/**/*.scss"],
                tasks: ["sass", "autoprefixer", "shell:jekyllBuild"]
            }
        }
    });


    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask("serve", ["shell:jekyllServe"]);
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["open", "concat", "uglify", "sass", "autoprefixer", "jade", "shell:jekyllBuild", "watch"]);
};
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In the watch task, try using this pattern: `files: ['js/{,*/}*.js']` instead of `files: ["js/*.js", "js/**/*.js"]` ?

Comment: @TonyBarnes Tried that, the watch task is still not registering any change.

Comment: Is it just the scripts that aren't being watched - are the HTML and CSS files working correctly? Obviously this is hard to debug without the codebase. I would maybe try separating the `watch` task from the `default` task and debug from there.

Comment: Just the scripts, the rest is watched correctly.

Comment: Try removing the 'site' method from the watch task, so the scripts are run first.

Comment: if I remove site, it will run, but as soon as the site is in there, it will not work anymore

Comment: Excellent! I think this is the culprit: `!_site/*.*`  - try removing those (in the site method).

Comment: that's it. Any other possibility how I can exclude the folder from the watch? Because _site is what is built, I don't really want grunt to watch it.

Comment: Hmm i'm not sure, doesn't seem to be anything coming from google about grunt tasks supporting underscores. Could you not rename the directory to `dist` or `site`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lays within your `site` method, in the `watch` task.

If you remove these, it should work:

```
"!_site/*.*", "!_site/**/*.*"
```

Grunt doesn't seem to like the underscores inline with the `!`.

I'm not sure how to workaround this whilst keeping the underscore, but you could always rename the directory to be `site` or `dist`, instead of `_site`.

Comment: After the rename everything works. Thanks a ton, would have never thought an underscore could be the problem!

Comment: @KreaTief Pleasure! Glad I could help :)